# grouped_collection_select for has_many :through Association not Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have a scenario where I created a few has_many :through associations which I am having trouble updating.  I do appreciate any help.

Here is my setup:

- ruby 1.9.3p392
- Rails 3.2.13

Here is the scenario:

- I have 3 models that are related
- There are many Industries, many Keywords, and many Conferences
- Industries have many Keywords
- Conferences have an Industry
- Conferences choose Keywords based on its Industry

Keywords has a basic CRUD model. Creating an Industry then adding Keywords works fine.

My relationship for Conferences, Industries, and Keywords is where I am having issues. I am trying to update Conference information, change the Industry that it is currently associated with, choose new Keywords based on the new Industry all in the same form. When I remove the Keywords element out of the mix, the update works. But when all three are there, then I get the errors.

My relationship for Industries and Keywords are:

```
class IKeywordable < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :industry_id, :keyword_id

belongs_to :industry
belongs_to :keyword

end
```

---

```
class CKeywordable < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :conference_id, :keyword_id

belongs_to :conference
belongs_to :keyword
end
```

---

Here are the Models:

```
class Industry < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, 
                :conferences_attributes,
                :i_keywordables_attributes, 
                :keywords,
                :keywords_attributes,
                :keyword_ids

validates       :name, presence: true
validates       :name, uniqueness: true

# Associations
has_many    :conferences
accepts_nested_attributes_for :conferences

#Keywords
has_many :i_keywordables
has_many :keywords, through: :i_keywordables
accepts_nested_attributes_for :i_keywordables
accepts_nested_attributes_for :keywords

end
```

---

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible 
               :name, :profile_id, :active, :rating, 
               :c_keywordables_attributes,
               :i_keywordables_attributes,
               :industries_atributes

# Associations

#Industries
  has_many :i_keywordables
  has_many :industries, through: :i_keywordables
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :i_keywordables

#Conferences
  has_many :c_keywordables
  has_many :conferences, through: :c_keywordables
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :c_keywordables

end
```

---

```
class Conference < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible 
              :name, :address1, :address2, :city, :email,
              :web, :profile_id, :state_id, :conference, 
              :description, :date_start, :date_end, :venue, :venue_web, 
              :organizer, :organizer_web, :c_keywordables_attributes, 
              :industry_attributes, :industry_id,
              :industry, :keyword_ids

# Associations

belongs_to :state
belongs_to :industry
accepts_nested_attributes_for :industry

#Keywords
has_many :c_keywordables
has_many :keywords, through: :c_keywordables
accepts_nested_attributes_for :c_keywordables

serialize :keywords, Array

  def to_s
     state_id
  end

end
```

Here is the Conference/edit.html.erb

```
  <h2>edit <%= @conference.name %></h2>
        <%= form_for  @conference do |c| %>
            <%= c.label :name %>
            <%= c.text_field :name %>
            <%= c.label :address1 %>
            <%= c.text_field :address1 %>
            <%= c.label :address2 %>
            <%= c.text_field :address2 %>
            <%= c.label :city %>
            <%= c.text_field :city %>
            <%= c.label :state_id%>
            <%= c.collection_select :state_id, State.order(:name), :id, :name %>
            <%= c.label :email %>
            <%= c.text_field :email %>
            <%= c.label :web %>
            <%= c.text_field :web %>
       <hr width="80%">
            <%= c.label :industry_id %>
            <%= c.collection_select :industry_id, Industry.order(:name), :id, :name %>
      <br />
            <%= c.fields_for :industry, @industry do |ci| %>
             <%= ci.label :keyword_id %>
             <%= ci.grouped_collection_select :keywords, Industry.order(:name),
                :keywords, 
                :name, 
                :id, 
                :name, 
                {:include_blank => true}, { :multiple => true }
                 %>
       <% end %>
    <br />
<p><%= c.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

---

Here is the Conference Controller:

```
def edit
    @conference = Conference.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @conference = Conference.find(params[:id])
        if @conference.update_attributes(params[:conference])
            redirect_to action: "all", notice: 'conference was successfully updated.'
        else
            render action: "edit" 
        end
end
```

---

The view renders fine but when I submit a change, I get an error. The error that I am seeing is:

**Couldn't find Industry with ID=3 for Conference with ID=1**

Here are the parameters passed:

**{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put",   "authenticity_token"=>"k9fcAXF/iOXt3oVuTcxeDCaWOfE2PrVlBvFbQG8Mo/I=", "conference"=>{"name"=>"test conference", "address1"=>"address 1", "address2"=>"address 2", "city"=>"City", "state_id"=>"38", "email"=>"test@example.com", "web"=>"www.example.com", "industry_id"=>"1", "industry_attributes"=>{"keywords"=>["", "6", "5"], "id"=>"3"}}, "commit"=>"Update Conference", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"conferences", "id"=>"1"}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AndyV, I finally resolved this issue. It turned out to be an issue with how I was calling the Associations.  I went into the console to investigate more how I was interacting with the Associations.  I wanted to associate keywords to conferences thru industry, which was wrong. So since I have:

```
 has_many :c_keywordables
 has_many :keywords, through: :c_keywordables
```

I could call keywords directly. So in the console, I could do:

```
 > c = Conference.first
 > c.keyword_ids
 > []
 > c.keyword_ids = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
 => [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

So I went to using a basic check box form to try and get things to work:

*With help from Railscast*:

```
<% Keyword.all.each do |keyword| %>
  <p>
   <%= check_box_tag "conference[keyword_ids][]", keyword.id, @conference.keyword_ids.include?(keyword.id) %>
   <%= keyword.name %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And it worked!  Now I will go back and try a little more complex form to get it to look like I wanted.

Thanks for all of the help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is a collision between the following two statements in your Conference class:

```
class Conference
  ...

  has_many :keywords, through: :c_keywordables

  ...

  serialize :keywords, Array do
    ...
  end
end
```

The first reference to keywords is expecting to build an ActiveRecord association to the Keywords table while the second reference is expecting a db-backed attribute (column) named keywords which will hold a serialized (yaml) representation of array data.  They're fighting over how to help you and you're the loser in the battle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I commented out 'serialize :keyword, Array do'  but still get the same error  _"authenticity_token"=>"GOJBEAHuPz2swO1zTXVgvgi9+JLBdIlSitnkThH6YRs=", "conference"=>{"name"=>"test conference", "address1"=>"address 1", "address2"=>"address 2", "city"=>"city", "state_id"=>"38", "email"=>"test@example.com", "web"=>"www.example.com", "industry_id"=>"2", "industry_attributes"=>{"keywords"=>[""], "id"=>"3"}}, "commit"=>"Update Conference", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"conferences", "id"=>"1"}_   Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I'd overlooked the params.  When you use nested attributes in Rails you're fundamentally saying, "I want to update this main object with ...abc... and the associated object with ...xyz...".  In this case, you're saying "I want to update Conference #1 with the conference params AND update Industry#3 with the industry_attributes hash."  I suspect that that is not what you intend.

If, instead, you want to create the association between the Conf and Industry AND the Conf and Keywords, then eliminate the attributes_for.  The params hash should contain industry_id and keyword_ids.

Comment: First when I remove **accepts_nested_attributes_for :industry** I receive an error "_unknown attribute: industry_attributes_". So then I remove the **:industry_attributes** from **attr_accessible** and I get  a "_Can't mass-assign protected attributes: industry_attributes_" error.

Comment: Check your form.  I assume that part of the form presents checkboxes from which the user selects keywords.  That part of the form is written so that the "keywords" array is being returned within industry_attributes.  If you inspect the HTML form, the name of the checkboxes probably say "conference[industry_attributes][keywords][]".  That's the part of the form that needs to be changed -- they should be f.checkbox :keyword_ids instead of the attributes_for.

Comment: I was using a select select box as illustrated in the Railscast episode on Dynamic Select Menus but I am thinking that I need to simplify it first, with check boxes, and then go from there. I will re-post my results. Thanks!!

Comment: I was just guessing that you were using checkboxes.  The UI representation is not really important -- the key is that the form us still attempting to use industry_attributes but you don't want to use them.